# How do I manually compile an Android App that requires AppCompatActivity?

Tags: android, android-activity, development-environment, extends, appcompatactivity

I am compiling an android application from scratch without a dedicated IDE such as *android studio*. But I am using the necessary *android tools*. The application compiles fine when I have created a basic application that extends `Activity.class`.
But, once I attempt to

`import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity`

and

`extends AppCompatActivity`

in the MainActivity class definition, the compilation breaks down with the error

`the hierarchy of the type MainActivity is inconsistent`

What exactly does such an error mean in general android development? And then, if anyone compiles android applications without gradle/maven support, what classes do I need to include to compile an app that uses `AppCompatActivity.class`?

I have compiled a similar project on *Android studio* or running a gradle build. I have been practising building without the specialist tools for a bit, and sadly this time, I also find that I am practising in an environment that does not support those tools.

So, any assistance will be appreciated. I tried to download `activity-1.5.1.jar` dependencies from the *Google maven repository* one by one, it contains `AppCompatActivity.class`. But, I have had no luck whatsoever in getting a working product.